# Usage of “d'eau” vs “de l'eau”

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, partitif

I'm confused about when to use “*d'eau*” and when to use “*de l'eau*”. For example, if someone asks “what is in that carafe?”, I think it is correct to answer “*c'est de l'eau*”. But if you ask for a carafe of water, you ask for a “*carafe d'eau*”.

In what situations do you use “*de l'eau*” and when do you use “*d'eau*”?

Comment: I also have trouble with "de l'eau" and "d'eau". I don't understand why they say "j'ai de l'eau" and "je n'ai pas d'eau". Why not "Je n'ai pas de l'eau"?

Comment: 'du', 'de la', 'de l'' and 'des' are truncated to simply 'de' in a negative construction. In English, it is also common to change the form of the indefinite article in negative constructions, from 'some' to 'any'; e.g. "I'll take some apples", and "I won't take any apples".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are several words that have the same spelling.

In *c'est de l'eau*, ***de l'*** is a [partitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive) article (*[article partitif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif)*). It is the singular, contracted form of the partitive article; other forms are ***de la*** bière (singular feminine), ***du*** vin (singular masculine), ***des*** oranges pressées (plural). Many uses of the partitive article can be expressed in English with the word *some* (even if it would be more idiomatic to omit *some* here): “the jug contains (some) water”.

In *une carafe d'eau*, ***d'*** is a [preposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition) (the contracted form of ***de***). This is one of the few cases in French where a common noun is not preceded by an article. Roughly speaking, *de* followed by a noun with no article indicates the origin of a process, the whole from which a part is made, or the purpose of an object (for more details: [TLF de¹ I.B](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)). *Une carafe d'eau* = a jug of (= containing) water.¹ *Une carafe de verre* (*en verre* would be more idiomatic here) = a jug (made) of glass. *Un cœur de pierre* = a heart (made) of stone. *Une rangée de chaises* = a row of chairs.

There are other cases where that same preposition *de* is followed by the definite article le/la/l'/les; it is then contracted to ***du*** / ***de la*** / ***de l'*** / ***des***. This is the case when *de* indicates possession: *la maison du boulanger* = the baker's house. This is also the case when *de* indicates an attribute of an object: *le bord de l'eau* = (lit.) the edge of the water. This is also the case in most cases when *de* introduces a complement of a verb: *sortir de l'eau* = to get out of the water.

¹ 
<sub>A jug designed to hold water would be *une carafe **à** eau*.</sub>

Comment: Fantastic response; very clear. Thanks!

Comment: In the second sense (mentioned preposition), *de* is also called complement of noun.

Comment: Could you explain this sentence: 'This is the case when de indicates possession: la maison du père de Pierre = Pierre's father's house'?

Are you referring to du or de when you say there's a preposition with a definite article? pere de Pierre sounds like possession to me, but is missing the definite article.

Maybe you could use an example that doesn't contain both usages?

Comment: @Martin I was refering to *maison du …*. Good point that it's a bad example, I've changed it.