# Are "de la bière" and "de bière" both acceptable?

Tags: grammaire, articles, partitif

Are the following sentences both correct?

1. Je donne **de la bière** à Jean;
2. Je donne **de bière** à Jean.

Comment: See here: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1556

Comment: "Je donne de bière à Jean" sera sans doute compris "Je donne deux bières à Jean".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the second one is wrong.

We say:

> Une bouteille de bière *(A bottle of beer)*.

We only use the *de* to say "a bottle *of* beer".

Therefore, we also say:

> J’ai bu *de la* bière *(I drank (some) beer)*.

Comment: Would "Je donne une bière à Jean" be correct too?

Comment: yes it's correct :)

Comment: Note that "Je donne une bière à Jean" means an exact quantity (a bottle, a can or a full glass), while "Je donne de la bière à Jean" can be anything from a sip to an indefinite number of bottles.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is correct. 
You cannot say "Je donne de bière à Jean" as there is no quantity noun.

**Quantities, Weights, Measures** in French must be followed by **de + noun** without the definite or partitive article. For example, a kilogram of oranges = un kilo d'oranges, NOT un kilo *des* pommes.

Answer (score 2):

No, *de la* (as well as *du*, *des* and *de l'*) is the partitive article.  It is required when talking about things which - as a general but not absolute rule - can be counted.  English does not require this.  'I have money'.  'I am eating fruit'.  And so on.  In French, that would be *j'ai de l'argent* and *je mange du fruit*.

The rules are:

- masculine singular - *du*
- feminine singular - *de la*
- masculine *or* singular beginning with vowel - *de l'*
- plural - *des*

So in your example, it would be, *je donne de la bière*.

However, if you're sitting there with a bottle in your hand and hand it to someone, it would be *je donne la bière*, but only because you're talking about one particular beer.

Comment: “Je mange du fruit” is weird. *Fruit* is an entity in French not a substance.

Comment: Je mange un fruit, or je mange des fruits. You do not say je mange du fruit in a standard context.