# How to choose between “de la” and “du”?

Tags: articles, genre

Consider the following answer I read to the question:

> Quelle est la différence entre AOC et une AOP?
>
> Answer: Ces deux labels garantissent des normes très strictes sur le plan de l'origine, ***de la*** production et ***du*** traitement.

Why the usage of *de la* with *production* and *du* with *traitement*? Could it be interchanged?

Comment: This answers your question.http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1560/358

Comment: @Laure: the two questions are distinct. It just happens that an answer to another question contains useful information, but new, possibly better and more specifically targeted, answers to this question are welcome. It can't be closed as a duplicate unless it is really a duplicate or subsumed by another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tout simplement parce que *production* est féminin, on utilise naturellement ***de la*** alors que *traitement* est masculin, et on remplace le *de le* par sa contraction ***du***.

Ils ne sont pas interchangeables car ils  dépendent du genre du mot qui suit.