# Why is "de l'eau" changed to "d'eau" in the negative sentence?

Tags: grammaire, articles, partitif

> Les garçons ont **de l'eau**. (The boys have [some] water)
>   Les garçons n'ont pas **d'eau**. (The boys do not have water)

Here are the things I am aware of:

- I have read [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1560/5853)
- `de la` has been changed to `de l'` and means "some" here.
- `de` means `of`
- `de la` can also mean `of the`
- `d'eau` is the contracted form of `de eau` and means `of water`

Despite the above facts, I still do not understand why in the second sentence, "**de l'eau**" has been changed to "**d'eau**". Why is the following sentence wrong?

> Les garçons n'ont pas de l'eau.

For me, "Les garçons n'ont pas d'eau" is literally translated to "The boys do not have *of water*" which does not make sense to me.

Can I conclude that "The boys do not have meat" should be translated to "Les garçons n'ont pas **de viande**" instead of "Les garçons n'ont pas **de la viande**"?

Comment: The partitive used to denote absence of something is *de* alone (You can find a detailed breakdown of the many uses of *de* here: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570)

Comment: «Pas d'eau» does not mean «of water».It means «any water» ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a negative sentence "pas de" is never followed by an article. For example:

> "Je veux de l'eau".
> *Negative*: " Je ne veux pas d'eau".
>
> "J'ai acheté des livres". *Negative*: "Je n'ai pas acheté de livres".
>
> "Il a de la pitié pour elle". *Negative*: "Il n'a pas de pitié pour elle".
>
> "Il mange des haricots" *Negative*: "Il ne mange pas de haricots".

With "c'est" or "ce sont", you would use an article. For example:

> "C'est une bonne occasion". Negative: "Ce n'est pas une bonne occasion".
>
> "Ce sont des livres très rares". Negative: "Ce ne sont pas des livres très rares".

Comment: It is not the case with *être*, *devenir* : *ça n’est pas de l’eau, ça ne deviendra pas du vin**.