# L'article partitif : « de l'aide »

Tags: grammaire, partitif

Est-ce que on emploie l'article partitif avec le nom « aide » ?

Par exemple, dit-on « J'ai besoin de l'aide » ou « J'ai besoin d'aide » ?

Ou « Tu veux de l'aide » ou « Tu veux d'aide » ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je pense que le problème n'est pas le mot *aide*, mais la combinaison de la préposition *de* suivie de l'article partitif.

On a besoin de quelque chose. Si le quelque chose est *de l'eau*, on devrait *<strike>*avoir besoin de de l'aide*</strike>, si c'est *du pain*, c'est *<strike>*avoir besoin de du pain*</strike> qu'il faudrait. Mais ça ne se dit pas et on a besoin d'aide comme on a besoin de pain, l'article partitif (*de l'* ou *du*) disparaissant après la préposition.  Par contre on peut avoir besoin de l'aide de Pierre ou du pain d'hier.  Mais *de l'* est ici la préposition *de* suivie de l'article défini *l'* et *du* est la contraction de la préposition *de* et de l'article *le* et non l'article partitif *de l'* ou *du*.  Je n'exclus pas la possibilité d'avoir un contexte où l'article défini est possible sans complément supplémentaire même si je n'en vois pas pour le moment.

Par contre on veut quelque chose, si cette chose est *de l'aide*, on veut de l'aide, si c'est *du pain* on veut du pain, avec *de l'* et *du* qui sont les articles partitifs. *<strike>*On veut d'aide.*</strike> et *<strike>*on veut de pain*</strike> ne sont pas possibles.

Voir aussi [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/10869/176).

Answer (score 3):

> J'ai besoin d'aide, tu veux de l'aide ?

Ou encore « Veux-tu de l'aide ? »

« J'ai besoin de l'aide » emploie un article défini « le », ce qui implique que l'aide est désignée (« j'ai besoin de l'aide de *ce monsieur* »). Il ne s'agit donc pas ici d'un article partitif mais d'un article défini.

La raison pour laquelle on demande « Tu veux de l'aide » est la même que dans la réponse suivante :
[Usage of “d'eau” vs “de l'eau”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/usage-of-deau-vs-de-leau/1560)

L'[article partitif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif) est ici proche d'un article indéfini, car la quantité d'aide n'est pas connue à l'avance.

Je ne suis cependant pas linguiste, il se peut que des erreurs se soient glissées dans mes explications. Libre à quiconque de me corriger.