# Understanding an explanation concerning the use of a preposition followed by a type of article (défini, partitif)?

Tags: prépositions, articles, partitif

From [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/21842):

> On a besoin de quelque chose. Si le quelque chose est *de l'eau*, on
>   devrait *<strike>*avoir besoin de de l'aide*</strike>, si c'est *du
>   pain*, c'est *<strike>*avoir besoin de du pain*</strike> qu'il
>   faudrait. Mais ça ne se dit pas et on a besoin d'aide comme on a
>   besoin de pain, l'article partitif (*de l'* ou *du*) disparaissant
>   après la préposition.  Par contre on peut avoir besoin de l'aide de
>   Pierre ou du pain d'hier.  **Mais *de l'* est ici la préposition *de*
>   suivie de l'article défini *l'* et *du* est la contraction de la
>   préposition *de* et de l'article *le* et non l'article partitif *de
>   l'* ou *du*.**  Je n'exclus pas la possibilité d'avoir un contexte où
>   l'article défini est possible sans complément supplémentaire même si
>   je n'en vois pas pour le moment.

But if I where to translate fully I would get, "But *de l’* here is the preposition *de*  followed by the definite article *l’* and *du* is the contraction of the preposition *de* and of the article *le* and NOT the article partitif  *de l’ or du*. "

I just get stumped by the last line. Non means *not* right?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit complicated, effectively, but the meaning is this:
***"de l'"*** can be either an *article partitif*, like in this example:

**"je veux de l'aide"** (*"I want some help"*). Here, "*de l'*" is an ***article partitif*** , that might be translated by "some" (and even the word "*some*" may be omitted in English: "I want help").

But here's a second example:
**"j'ai besoin de l'aide de Pierre"** (*I need Peter's help*). In this case, "*de l'*" doesn't mean "*some*", but "de" is here a required preposition because "*avoir besoin*" is not a transitive verb, so we must use "*avoir besoin de*", and so "l'" here is independant